# Add Columns VS Foreign Key on new table

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have a post process application that needs to add three values to every entry of a millions of record table.  The process runs every 15 minutes and will need to add three values to each row of this table.  Is it better to add three columns to this table(update) or to make a new table with a foreign key on it(insert)?

EDIT:
Thought this was a more general question, but per request:

```
CREATE TABLE `position` (
`idPosition` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`idRover` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`TimeHack` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
`Milliseconds` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`n` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`e` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`z` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`nx` double DEFAULT '0',
`ny` double DEFAULT '0',
`nz` double DEFAULT '1',
`valid` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`Reverse` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Azimuth` double DEFAULT '0',
`cutfill` double DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idPosition`),
UNIQUE KEY `positionrovertime` (`idRover`,`valid`,`TimeHack`,`Milliseconds`),
 KEY `fkPositionidRover` (`idRover`),
CONSTRAINT `fkPositionidRover` FOREIGN KEY (`idRover`) REFERENCES `rover` (`idRover`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=574050 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

not my design, just what i got to work with.  I know there are a bunch of WTF's.  I need to add either 3 columns that are doubles or a new table with four columns with PK and FK on the PK of this table.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Show us your tentative queries.

Answer (score 0):

it will depend on your requirements and you can check it with nomalization guideline but altering a table with millions of record will not be easy task so if you realy want to add it to same table create temp table with those 3 additional columns and then load all the data from old table to new one. drop old table and rename new table to old table name.

if you are adding it to separate table always you have to join those two tables when your retrieving data in that case you can add foreign key to the other tables but you have to follow the above mention process becouse altering is not an easy task.

Comment: I have added columns before.  Takes a bit of time but 3 million entries wasn't too bad.  What is better for preformance.  Is update as fast as insert?  Is a foreign key on primary ID equal speed to an additional column with selects?